# How to test FCM push notification in simulator for iOS XCode 11.4?

Tags: xcode, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, simulator

Is possible to test fcm iOS push notification in simulator or can I convert fcm push notification json format to apns format for testing in simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can test push notifications on the simulator if using Xcode 11.4 or higher.

> “Simulator supports simulating remote push notifications, including
>   background content fetch notifications. In Simulator, drag and drop an
>   APNs file onto the target simulator. The file must be a JSON file with
>   a valid Apple Push Notification Service payload, including the “aps”
>   key. It must also contain a top-level “Simulator Target Bundle” with a
>   string value matching the target application‘s bundle identifier.

Comment: try any of these if you don't know how: https://tudip.com/blog-post/5-steps-to-test-push-notification-in-the-simulator/, https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-the-ios-simulator-2988092ba931, https://medium.com/globant-mobile-studio-india/send-push-notifications-to-the-ios-simulator-3a78b6689cf

Comment: yes, i tested APNS payload in simulator, but FCM notification payload is different format. So, I can't test FCM notification payload in simulator. Is there is anyway to test FCM payload in simulator?

Comment: You know you can contact Firebase tech support directly? They answer within 24 hrs (maybe not weekends though)

Comment: np, come back and post the answer. Good luck

Comment: sure i will post the answer

Comment: @hardiksa, We can't test fcm push notification in Simulator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63942759/test-fcm-notification-on-ios-simulator?noredirect=1&lq=1